# How to disable showing uncought exceptions in developer mode?

Tags: magento2, log, developer-mode

I switched to developer mode and I see nothing but uncought exceptions log instead of storefront. Something like this:

[image]

Can I disable it somehow? To show my storefront in developer mode?

I have already commented out

```
    #ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in app/bootstrap.php

and renamed local.xml to local.xml.sample 
in pub/errors.

Answer (score 3):

That's the whole point of developer mode. To see anything that goes wrong.
If you want to go back to production mode you can change the mode in `app/etc/env.php`. Look for the word `developer` and replace it with `production`. cache clearing might be needed.

Comment: I dont want care about those exceptions right now just to hide them and I need to stay in developer mode.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try fixing the exceptions since the message is pretty clear or switch to production mode with `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`.
There are probably other options but they will just hide your problem instead of actually finding the cause and fix the underlying issue.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do :) Hide problems for now and continue developing. I need to stay in developer mode.

Comment: Are you working remotely? It seems that you are in Mumbai :) so

Comment: Ok I got rid of those exceptions and now it works but im still wondering how can i disable showing those logs in the future.

Comment: This is more of a philosophical discussion. An exception is not something you should look over, you have other errors types who won’t disrupt the execution of your app. You can even catch the exception and do something instead of showing it, but an uncatched exception shouldn’t be “hidden”

Answer (score 1):

I inherited a site with the same problem. Quickest way around it is to set ini_set('display_errors', 0) in ./app/bootstrap.php. You'll stay in developer mode but the site won't print errors. You can also leave display_errors=1 but set error_reporting(E_ERROR) instead of E_ALL and Magento won't print notices or warnings, only errors and above.

[image: bootstrap.php kludge]